# How can I use Tensorflow lite to detect object landmarks without labelmaps.txt file?

Tags: java, android, image, regression, tensorflow-lite

I have a worked tflite model and I want to integrate this model to get human eye region landmarks.
I tried and I followed many tutorials on the web but I didn't get any solution.
The problem is that Tensorflow Documentation doesn't have any resource about how to use Tensorflow lite model to detect one object without classification ( without using labels.txt), I mean regression output ( just values in array list ).

I followed the MLKit custom model tutorial, For the first time, I was sure it would work but it doesn't.

**UPDATE**

This is the architecture of the model that I use: ( I have used netron to get nodes) 
[image]

I get false values, I saw that the problem is maybe in the TensorFlow lite model, but I backed away from what I said when I test the model with a python script and I got same results than the frozen model.

I really need to know who works or who have any idea how to integrate TensorFlow Lite model with regression output on Android?

Comment: *I get false values,* - maybe lack of training

Comment: No, I test on the same image but I didn't get the same values. I didn't have posted any of images or code because I have recently posted a similar question

Comment: This is the reference site that I use https://blog.floydhub.com/instagram-street-art/

Comment: Thanks, what you have posted doesn't include the Android java implementation part.

Answer (score 0):

For TFL, you can definitely do it with the correct choice of inputs and outputs node. Instead of using the last classification output node, cut the model until the logit you needed.

Not sure about MLKit though.

Comment: I have successfully got probabilities values with MLKit but the problem is they are not the same than values that I get with Tensorflow lite using python script and values with Frozen graph, please see the update section 
in my post, and this is my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442372/tflite-prediction-is-totally-different-than-frozen-inference-graph-prediction